# Safe pointer casting : static_cast or dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, c++14, inheritance, casting

Context: I'm using the clone pattern for creating copies of polymorphic classes which may use virtual inheritance (I hope to get rid of the latter). So when calling `foo.clone()` I'm guaranteed to get the same type as `foo` even though the `clone` function might return only the base class (say `ICloneable`)

So I wrapped the clone call into a freestanding `clone` function which casts the pointer to the class passed and additionally puts it into a `unique_ptr`.

However the cast is a problem. `dynamic_cast` has too much overhead as I already know what type I'll get and `static_cast` doesn't work with base to derived casts on virtual bases.

So this is what I came up with:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename = void>
struct is_static_castable : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_static_castable<T, U, decltype(void(static_cast<U>(std::declval<T>())))> : std::true_type
{};

template<typename To, typename From>
std::enable_if_t<is_static_castable<From*, To*>::value, To*>
safePtrCast(From* from)
{
    return static_cast<To*>(from);
}

template<typename To, typename From>
std::enable_if_t<!is_static_castable<From*, To*>::value, To*>
safePtrCast(From* from)
{
    return dynamic_cast<To*>(from);
}

template<class T>
auto clone(const T* obj)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(safePtrCast<T>(obj->clone()));
}
```

Some notes:

- C++14
- `void` conversion in `is_static_castable` is required so MSVC 2015 does not fail for `is_static_castable<int, int>`, no idea why
- `safePtrCast` can be enhanced with an `assert(dynamic_cast...` if wanted
- return type `enable_if` used due to a bug in GCC 8: https://godbolt.org/z/6-C6CS

Any remarks on potential issues?
Possible cases I missed?
Improvements to make it more readable?

Otherwise feel free to use the code for own projects :)

The non-MSVC version of `is_static_castable` is slightly clearer:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename = U>
struct is_static_castable : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_static_castable<T, U, decltype(static_cast<U>(std::declval<T>()))> : std::true_type
{};
```

Example for not using covariant return types:

```
struct ICloneable{ virtual ICloneable* clone() = 0; };
struct Middle: ICloneable{...};
struct Final: Middle{ Final* clone(); };

void foo(Middle* bar){
  auto barCloned = clone(bar); // Should be a unique_ptr<Middle>
}
```

Comment: Re "`void` conversion in `is_static_castable` is required so MSVC 2015 does not fail for `is_static_castable<int, int>`, no idea why": otherwise the type is not `void`, and `typename = void` does not select it. This is not restricted to MSVC 2015.

Comment: Oh right. I added a note how it would look like for all but MSVC (not using `void`)

Comment: "even though the clone function might return only the base class"... can you show an example class hierarchy that requires this? The normal solution is to use covariant return types (this is actually the classic motivating example for the language feature): https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Covariant_Return_Types

Comment: I took me a while to find the use case again but now I added it: It occurs when you have a pointer to a class from the middle of the hierarchy. Only the final classes should implement the clone function (I might even `static_assert` this) to avoid mistakes. Obviously this is use-case dependent but for this question assume that there are "middle" classes which have other pure-virtual functions so a clone implementation there would not be useful.